# TMX: Only 1 tilset per layer is supported

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

i am take two layer Background and Cloud and in background i put background image and cloud layer i put cloud image and both TMX add to my project and when run i got error TMX: Only 1 tilset per layer is supported but only one layer use it run successfully..

[image]

Code:

```
    CCTMXTiledMap *TiledFirst = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"BackgroundTiled.tmx"];
    [self addChild:TiledFirst];

    CCTMXTiledMap *Clould = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"Clould.tmx"];
    [self addChild:Clould];
```

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d only supports one tileset per layer. This error occurs as soon as you add one tile (even a completely transparent one) from another tileset onto the same layer. Since there's no easy way to identify these tiles in Tiled and your map still being simple the easiest fix is to delete and re-add both layers, then make sure you add only tiles of one tileset to either layer.

PS: both [KoboldTouch](http://koboldtouch.com) and [Kobold Kit](http://koboldkit.com) do not have this restriction.

Comment: id move=[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10.0 position:ccp(-1000, 0)];
        
        id repeat=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:move];
        
        [self.Cloud runAction:repeat];